# SSRS - Proper syntax for expression value for IN filter having multiple integers?

Tags: reporting-services

This seems like it should be simple but I can't seem to get the proper syntax.

I'm trying to add a filter to a dataset, where the values need to be based on a parameter value.

I know I can do a basic IN filter like this (the parameter named MyField is of type INT):

`Expression: [MyField]`
`Operator: In`
`Value: 4,5`

The dataset only returns records where MyField is 4 or 5.

But, I only want to show 4 & 5 if MyParameter = 1 or 2. Otherwise I want to show 5 & 6. I tried setting an expression for the value like:

`=IIf(Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 1 OR Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 2, "4,5", "5,6")`

This results in an error about "Cannot compare data of types System.Int64 and System.String".

I also tried:

`=IIf(Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 1 OR Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 2, "CInt(4),CInt(5)", "CInt(5),CInt(6)")`

But that gave the same error. How to I pass multiple integers like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set up another multi-value integer parameter and put it at the end of your parameter list. Make it Hidden so the user never sees it.

Now you always want to show 5 so let's add that as a default value for this parameter. Click Add to add another default value. This time we need to enter a formula to select whether we want 4 or 6:

```
=IIf(Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 1 OR Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 2, 4, 6)
```

Now you have a multi-value parameter containing two values: either 4 and 5, or 5 and 6, depending on the value of the Timeframe parameter. Use this new parameter in your filter.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with your first expression. The problem is that you are passing a single string to the `IN` filter operator instead of what it expects, which is an array.

You can easily fix it like this ....

```
=IIf(Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 1 OR Parameters!Timeframe.Value = 2,
     SPLIT("4,5", ","),
     SPLIT("5,6", ",")
    )
```

`Split()` will return an array split by a delimiter so by hardcoding `"4,5"` for exmaple and telling it to split using commas we get the array we need.